# Lock keyword calls Monitor.Enter(Object) or Enter(Object, Boolean)?

Tags: c#, .net, locking, monitor

In [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) documentation of .NET Framework 4.5 I found a sentence, which says that lock keyword uses [Enter(Object, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498.aspx) method of Monitor:

> The functionality provided by the Enter and Exit methods is identical to that provided by the C# lock statement (SyncLock in Visual Basic), except that lock and SyncLock wrap the Enter(Object, Boolean) method overload and the Exit method in a try…finally block (Try…Finally in Visual Basic) to ensure that the monitor is released.

On the other hand in the overwiew of [Monitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf5de04k.aspx) there is:

> The Visual Basic SyncLock and C# lock statements use MonitorEnter to take the lock and MonitorExit to release it.

MonitorEnter in above refers to different version of Enter method than previous, namely: [Enter(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx)

In [Thread Synchronization (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx#Y370) for Visual Studio 2012 there is a sample how lock wraps Monitor:

```
System.Object obj = (System.Object)x;
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(obj);
try
{
    DoSomething();
}
finally
{
    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(obj);
}
```

There is also [Enter(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx) version.

What is true?
Does lock statement calls [Enter(Object, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498.aspx) or [Enter(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx)?
Whether there is any difference how it is really done?

Comment: They are both true.  Depends on what .NET version you target.

Comment: @HansPassant: I get those quotes only from .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Eric Lippert’s Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx):

> Recall that `lock(obj){body}` was [in C# 3.0 and earlier] a syntactic sugar for
>
> ```
> var temp = obj;
> Monitor.Enter(temp);
> try { body }
> finally { Monitor.Exit(temp); }
> ```
>
> The problem here is that if the compiler generates a no-op instruction between the monitor enter and the try-protected region then it is possible for the runtime to throw a thread abort exception after the monitor enter but before the try. In that scenario, the finally never runs so the lock leaks, probably eventually deadlocking the program. It would be nice if this were impossible in unoptimized and optimized builds.
>
> In C# 4.0 we've changed lock so that it now generates code as if it were
>
> ```
> bool lockWasTaken = false;
> var temp = obj;
> try { Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken); { body } }
> finally { if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(temp); }
> ```
>
> The problem now becomes someone else's problem; the implementation of Monitor.Enter takes on responsibility for atomically setting the flag in a manner that is immune to thread abort exceptions messing it up.
>
> So everything is good now, right?
>
> Sadly, no. [[...]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx)

On the other hand, the [C# 4.0 Language Specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552) says:

> A lock statement of the form
>
> ```
> lock (x) ...
> ```
>
> where x is an expression of a reference-type, is precisely equivalent to
>
> ```
> System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
> try {
>    ...
> }
> finally {
>    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x);
> }
> ```
>
> except that x is only evaluated once.

Comment: Documentation refers to 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012. Do they just copy paste out-of-date old text?

Comment: Probably Microsoft implements Enter(Object, Boolean) and thereby it breaks half of its documentation and the standard. Others probably implement standard.

Comment: Since Eric Lippert was [part of the C# design team](http://ericlippert.com/2012/11/29/fabulous-adventures/), there's a good chance he knows what he's talking about and that he is more correct than the documentation.

Comment: @yBee: We made the deliberate decision to not overly complicate the documentation; whether the `Enter` is inside the protected region or not is for the vast majority of cases invisible to the user. The C# compiler now generates the `Enter` inside the try if the version of the CLR being targetted has a public `Enter(obj, bool)` method and falls back to `Enter(obj)` if it does not; many versions of the CLR do not have an accessible `Enter(obj, bool)` method. Explaining all that in the spec is just unnecessarily confusing; what you really need to know is that locking is the same as `Enter`ing.